# only further evangelizing their particular brand of occultism

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm confused as to what the bolded phrase in the sentence modifies.

> Perhaps more revelatory, Sunny and Sonya reveal they “LARP as girls”
> with the “simps” they catch in the process **only further evangelizing
> their particular brand of occultism**.

Which interpretation is correct?

1. It is the act of them larping as girls that only further evangelizes it.
2. It is the act of "revealing" that they larp as girls that only further evangelizes it.
3. it is the simps they catch in the process that only further evangelize it.

Comment: In case people don't know (I didn't), "LARP (Live Action Role Playing), also called LARPing, is a character-driven type of gameplay that is conducted in the physical world. LARP combines elements of improvisational acting, pervasive gaming, cosplay (costume play) and role-playing games."

Comment: I would say (3). By the way, what is a 'simp'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I had to look up [simp](https://later.com/social-media-glossary/simp/), though I had heard of LARPing. I would say (3) too.

Comment: Thank you. I think simp refers to an overzealous fan who does anything to support a person they're a fan of.

Comment: Are these terms specialised to some age group (e.g. under 20s) or interest group (some kind of gamers)? Or is it something to do with stuff like Tik-Tok?

Comment: Yes, these terms are mostly used by young people, especially those familiar with online cultures

Comment: @noolodig This question may have been downvoted for a few reasons. (1) it's not about a specific aspect of learning English; (2) the example sentence is badly written; (3) based on your first and second guessed interpretations, you don't seem to know how to use the word "evangelize", and a dictionary might help you. I'm not here to evangelize for any of these reasons, just to give you things to consider.

Comment: I see. "evangelize" means to spread the gospel to someone, right? So isn't it possible to use evangelize here in the sense that (the revelation of) them pretending to be girls attracted a lot of people to their group, meaning that they spread their gospel to a larger audience by (revealing) the fact that they pretend to be girls?

Comment: Also, as a non-native speaker, getting downvoted due to the sentence being badly written feels pretty unfair. because I can't tell if it's well or badly written, I wouldn't even post questions in the first place if I knew that the sentence was just badly written and that was the source of my confusion.

Comment: After reading this a few times, it seems you are correct in being confused about what the phrase modifies. yes "the example sentence is badly written".

Comment: Honestly, the voting system on this site doesn't make any sense to me. It seems like it overly caters to answerers and doesn't care about us questioners. We ask questions because we want to know if (1) it's about a specific aspect of learning English, and if (2) the example sentence is badly written. Getting downvoted for these reasons is ridiculous because these things are exactly the reasons why we ask questions here. At least make it possible to see who downvoted for what reasons, and to protest if the reasons are unreasonable.

Comment: Well, I can't ask questions anymore so it doesn't matter, though.